# Java - JUnit Mockito method approach

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit, mocking

Just started learning Mockito, and I have method which will generate some code for later construct some request and store to database.

Is there any idea how to test this with specifically @Mock or I don't need that?

```
public String generateCode(byte[] input) {
    return StringUtils.join(DigestUtils.sha1Hex(input).toUpperCase();
}
```

Not sure that l understand Mockito to good for this kind of method...Thanks for any suggestions

```
@Autowired
RequestUtil requestUtil; // this is where generateCode method is

@Test
public void generateSuccesCode() {
    requestUtil.generateCode(input);
}
```

Should I create some byte[] before and proceed to generateCode parameter

Not sure how Mocking helps me with my method above

```
StringUtils.join(DigestUtils.sha1Hex(input).toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to use Mockito here at all.

Testing this method with a real value (and an expectation based on that value) is simple and offers complete coverage.

For example:

```
@Test
public void foo() {
    RequestUtil requestUtil = new RequestUtil();

    Assert.assertEquals("0BEEC7B5EA3F0FDBC95D0DD47F3C5BC275DA8A33", requestUtil.generateCode("foo".getBytes()));
}
```

This approach works as long as you have some expectation of what a valid output is for a given input.

If you have such an expectation then all I am suggesting is that you actually pass in a value and assert that the response meets this expectation.

If, however, you really have **no** expectation of what value `generateCode()` should return and hence your only expectation is that it will invoke `DigestUtils.sha1Hex()` and pass the response through `StringUtils.join()` then you'll have to use PowerMock to mock `DigestUtils`. For example:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({DigestUtils.class})
public class TestTest {

    private RequestUtil sut = new RequestUtil();

    @Test
    public void testGenerateCode() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(DigestUtils.class);

        byte[] input = "anInput".getBytes();
        final String hex = "0beec7";
        Mockito.when(DigestUtils.sha1Hex(input)).thenReturn(hex);

        String actual = sut.generateCode(input);
        Assert.assertEquals(hex.toUpperCase(), actual);
    }
}
```

FWIW, this approach introduces complexity with ~no additional benefit. I can't see a valid reason for doing that. The method is deterministic so I would recommend that you let your test case pass in a value and assert that the method always returns the expected generated output for that value.

Comment: I have updated the answer, attempting to make clear what I meant by the 'actual value' approach and also providing an example of mocking the internals of `generateCode()` using PowerMock.

Comment: Not sure what to put in "foo"getBytes()); part
always getting unit error expected "0BEEC7B5EA3F0FDBC95D0DD47F3C5BC275DA8A33" for example and always get was "some random string generated", how to hit this? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, i will see what l can do with this PowerMock, because l have no expectation of what value generateCode() should return, it's generate random hex String always

Comment: `DigestUtils.sha1Hex()` does **not** return a random string. Its output is predictable and deterministic for any given input.

Comment: Guess there is no way to hit expected and actual values in simple JUnit approach...will try with PowerMock.

Comment: The "simple JUnit approach" **is** the approach which uses expected and actual value. The first part of my answer shows an assertion for the input "foo", no matter how often you invoke `Digest.sha1Hex()` for "foo".getBytes() the answer will be the same so this is an example of using known inputs + outputs to test the `generateCode()` method.

Comment: Agree, thanks again, l will see what l can do with PowerMock part